# UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [] creator org [Org1MSP] - Hyperledger in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

My docker-compose is the same as the [default one](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-tools/blob/master/packages/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/docker-compose.yml), exepting that it has this additional code:

```
hyperledger:
  build: 
    context: .
  ports:
    - 8081:8081
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM hyperledger/composer-cli:0.19.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

USER root
RUN chown -R composer:composer .

USER composer 

RUN ls -la
# RUN composer archive create -t dir -n .

RUN rm -rf .stage && mkdir ./.stage 
RUN echo '{"name": "hyper-discover-network","x-type": "hlfv1","x-commitTimeout": 300,"version": "1.0.0","client": {"organization": "Org1","connection": {"timeout": {"peer": {"endorser": "300","eventHub": "300","eventReg": "300"},"orderer": "300"}}},"channels": {"composerchannel": {"orderers": ["orderer.example.com"],"peers": {"peer0.org1.example.com": {}}}},"organizations": {"Org1": {"mspid": "Org1MSP","peers": ["peer0.org1.example.com"],"certificateAuthorities": ["ca.org1.example.com"]}},"orderers": {"orderer.example.com": {"url": "grpc://orderer.example.com:7050"}},"peers": {"peer0.org1.example.com": {"url": "grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7051","eventUrl": "grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7053"}},"certificateAuthorities": {"ca.org1.example.com": {"url": "http://ca.org1.example.com:7054","caName": "ca.org1.example.com"}}}' > connection.json

EXPOSE 8081

USER root
RUN chmod 777 docker-entrypoint.sh 
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "composer" ]
```

And my docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -e

if [ "$1" = 'composer' ]; then
composer archive create -t dir -n .
echo '{...}' > connection.json

composer card create -p ./connection.json -u PeerAdmin -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin -f .stage/PeerAdmin.card  \
    -c crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem \
    -k crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/19ab65abbb04807dad12e4c0a9aaa6649e70868e3abd0217a322d89e47e1a6ae_sk

# composer-playground
composer card import -f .stage/PeerAdmin.card && composer card list && ls -la && pwd
echo 'som shit'
composer network install -a hyper-discover-network@0.0.1.bna -c PeerAdmin@hyper-discover-network 
fi
```

The error appears at `composer network install ...` line.
I am building this environment by executing: `./startFabric.sh && docker-compose up hyperledger`

[image]